# how to connect and insert map keys and values into derby database?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, java-8, derby

I have a java program and it produces the output as follows :

**termname :docname : termcount**

Forexample termname is hello and docname is :2 and termcount is :4

**hello:doc1:4**
.....
......

I stored all the values in a map.  here is the following program

```js
public class tuple {
   
   
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception{
        File file2 = new File("D:\\logs\\tuple.txt");
        PrintWriter tupled = new PrintWriter(file2, "UTF-8");
        List<Map<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Integer>map= new HashMap<>();;
        String word;
    //Iterate over documents
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        //map = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner tdsc = new Scanner(new File("D:\\logs\\AfterStem" + i + ".txt"));
        //Iterate over words
        while (tdsc.hasNext()) {
            word = tdsc.next();
            final Integer freq = map.get(word);
            if (freq == null) {
                map.put(word, 1);
            } else {
                map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
            }
        }
        list.add(map);
    }
    // tupled.println(list);
     //tupled.close();
    //Print result
  
   
   
   
    int documentNumber = 0;
    for (Map<String, Integer> document : list) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : document.entrySet()) {
            documentNumber++;
            //System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":doc"+documentNumber+":" + entry.getValue());
            tupled.print(entry.getKey());
            tupled.print(":doc:");
            tupled.print(Integer.toString(documentNumber));
            tupled.print(",");
            tupled.println(entry.getValue());
            
            
        }
        //documentNumber++;
    }
    tupled.close();
```

Now I want to store this values into derby database of neatbeans.
How I would be able to do that ?

Comment: To store values into a Derby database, you use the SQL INSERT statement, specifying the values as parameters to the statement. To insert multiple rows, you either execute the statement multiple times, or use the JDBC statement batch feature.

Comment: how to connect with derby database ?

Comment: If you're just getting started with Derby and with databases, I recommend reading some good JDBC tutorials, like the ones on Oracle's Java website. For Derby tutorials, a great place to start is with the Derby Getting Started guide: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/getstart/